# Why do I get "Incorrect Password" when connecting to a Mumble server? I never even used a password!

Tags: login, reinstall, certificate, mumble

I just reinstalled Mumble, and now when I try to login on my favourite server I get «Incorrect Password». Why is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you install Mumble for the first time, a certificated was created for you. *That* is your "password." You should've saved it somewhere safe, and reimported it when reinstalling Mumble. You didn't.

When you registered, or were registered with your favourite server, what actually happened was a binding between your certificate and your nickname. With that certificate, you can only login with that username; without that certificate, you cannot login with that username. You now need that certificate.

If you still have it saved somewhere, import it: open *Configuration* → *Certificate wizard*, then pick *Import certificate*. Select your certificate and continue; you'll be able to login normally.

If you don't have the certificate anymore, because you probably never even knew about this whole thingadongdong, what you must do is:

1. Ask an admin of your server to **delete your account.** (The relevant dialog can be reached via *Server* → *Registered users.*)
2. While he does that, open *Configuration* → *Certificate wizard*, then choose ***Export Certificate.*** Put it somewhere safe (say, Dropbox) for later retrieval.
3. While the admin processes your request, change your nickname to login anyway if you're in a hurry. ***Do not register!***
4. When the admin tells you he's done deleting your account, **log out**, then log in *with your "official" nick.*
5. **Register** with the server and ask the admin to regrant you the privs you previously had.

...and next time, remember to *import that certificate!* It's important.

Comment: Dropboxing the cert is a great idea.  Just did that with mine.