# Mumble exits with message "A referral was returned by the server"

Tags: mumble

I've tried to launch Mumble today but got this effort from Microsoft C++ instead:

> A referral was returned by the server

What does it mean? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to some kind of certificate snafu, [Mumble 1.2.3 no longer works on Windows.](http://blog.mumble.info/)

Uninstall Mumble, [download the latest copy from the website](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/) and install that. This should keep your certificate, so you don't need to worry about [incorrect passwords](https://superuser.com/questions/254045/why-do-i-get-incorrect-password-when-connecting-to-a-mumble-server-i-never-ev).

Comment: thanks a lot for that information! Windows' helpfull error messages are sometimes a real pain in the a...eye

Answer (score 0):

Run mumble in compatible mode (Windows XP SP3) with admin rights.